# Use cookies to toggle body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I've being bashing my head around finding a working solution for this.
Goal is to create a text size switcher for people with poor eyesight.
I have created three span elements with classes **small, medium and large**.

And I have a piece of code that almost gets the job done but it needs that cookie part.

```
$(function() {
    $(".font-toggle span").click(function() {
        var size = $(this).attr('class');
        $("body").attr("id", size);
        return false;
    });    
});
```

How can i use cookies to save my selection and add it after page refresh ?
Have been reading many stackoverflow posts about setting cookies but all of them feature only one toggle. Here I have three.

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/6xe9u582/3/)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".font-toggle span").click(function() {
        var size = $(this).attr('class');
        $("body").attr("id", size);
        if($.cookie('mycookie') == 'valueOfCookie'){
           $.cookie('mycookie', '');
        }
        else{
          $.cookie('mycookie', 'valueOfCookie');
        }
        
        return false;
    }); 
    if($.cookie('mycookie') == 'valueOfCookie'){
       $("body").attr("id", 'big-font');
    }
    else{
      $("body").removeAttr("id");
    }
});
```

```css
#big-font{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/releases/download/v1.4.1/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="font-toggle">
  <span class="big-font">
   Button
  </span>
</div>
<div>
  Text To Show
</div>
```

Comment: This works with only one toggle. I need to clear and add a new cookie after every class toggle. If I click span.small I set cookie small, bust after i click span.large i remove previous cookie small and reset it to large. Right now it is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/releases/download/v1.4.1/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  "use strict";


  $(document).ready(function() {
    let eyesight = $.cookie('eyesight');

    if (eyesight != undefined) {
      $("body").addClass(eyesight);
    } else 
      setEyesight('medium'); // Default size

    $(".font-toggle span").click(function() {
      setEyesight($(this).attr('class'));
    });
  });


  function setEyesight(size) {
    let eyesight = $.cookie('eyesight');

    if (eyesight != undefined) {
      $("body").removeClass(eyesight);
      $.removeCookie('eyesight');
    }

    $("body").addClass(size);
    $.cookie('eyesight', size);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that almost works as intended. But, stangely, if large is set via span click, it works. After page refresh, still works. Now, after clicking that other class, small, it removes class large and sets class small. NOW after page change previous class comes back, class large. Every page has its own class . Can I set a global cookie for the whole domain?

Comment: well cookies are always set for whole domain. Are you sure that this script is included in every page?

Comment: Still same, if one page have class "medium" then other can have "large" after toggling between them. Like remove cookie never gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/releases/download/v1.4.1/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    let eyesight = new Eyesight();
    eyesight.initialize();

    $(".font-toggle span").click(function() {
      eyesight.set($(this).attr('class'));
    });
  });

  function Eyesight() {
    let self = this;
    let name = "eyesight";
    let current = null;
    let _default = "medium";
    let data = $.cookie(name);

    // initialzie
    this.initialize = function() {
      if (data!= undefined) {
        $("body").addClass(data);
        current = data;
      } else 
        self.set(_default); // Default size

      // init cookie listener
      self.listener();
    };

    // set eyesight function
    this.set = function(size) {
      if (data != undefined) {
        $("body").removeClass(data);
        $.removeCookie(name);
      }

      $("body").addClass(size);
      $.cookie(name, size);
      current = size;
    };

    // eyesight cookie listener function
    this.listener = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        let cookie = $.cookie(name);

        if (cookie != undefined && cookie != current)
          self.set(cookie);

        self.listener();
      }, 100);
    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a bit better but still not working.
Maybe an example will help?
https://www.eesti.ee/eng/
In this page, there is a link "for visually impaired" that toggles a menu and inside there is a similar function that i need for my website.